# Sending email attachement using PHPMailer

Tags: php, csv, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email with an .csv attachment size is 7.5mb only and the email recipients send and receive limit is 10mb but it seems that the email was not sent but changing recipients email capacity to 20mb solves the issue.

Can someone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an attachment, it gets base64-encoded, which adds considerable overhead to the message size, in your case enough to take it over the size threshold. A better approach would be to make the item available via download link and send them that instead.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response ,  do you know some references regarding to your answer?

Comment: [RFC2045](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2045#section-6.8) defines base64 encoding, and the context of its use in email. The short version is that it encodes 3 bytes of input into 4 characters, resulting in a 33% overhead. The reason it needs to be encoded is that email can't transport binary data without corrupting it.